# Find group of strings that are anagrams

Tags: python, string, anagram

This question refers to [this problem on lintcode](http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/anagrams/). I have a working solution, but it takes too long for the huge testcase. I am wondering how can it  be improved? Maybe I can decrease the number of comparisons I make in the outer loop.

```
class Solution:
    # @param strs: A list of strings
    # @return: A list of strings
    def anagrams(self, strs):
        # write your code here
        ret=set()
        for i in range(0,len(strs)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(strs)):
                if i in ret and j in ret:
                    continue
                if Solution.isanagram(strs[i],strs[j]):
                    ret.add(i)
                    ret.add(j)

        return [strs[i] for i in list(ret)]


    @staticmethod
    def isanagram(s, t):
        if len(s)!=len(t):
            return False
        chars={}
        for i in s:
            if i in chars:
                chars[i]+=1
            else:
                chars[i]=1

        for i in t:
            if i not in chars:
                return False
            else:
                chars[i]-=1
                if chars[i]<0:
                    return False

        for i in chars:
            if chars[i]!=0:
                return False
        return True
```

**Update:** Just to add, not looking for built-in pythonic solutions such as using `Counter` which are already optimized. Have added Mike's suggestions, but still exceeding time-limit.

Comment: `I am wondering how can it be improved` - please have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - your question might be better suited for our partner site. Please have a look at CodeReview's how to ask first to make sure it's well received there.

Comment: Is your method supposed to return all strings that are anagrams of any other string?

Comment: Yes correct, any pair of anagrams.

Comment: `isanagram` method is way complex, looks like you're writing C code.  This is python, isanagram is just `return Counter(word1) == Counter(word2)` !

Comment: @wim I am trying to implement the algorithm and not use built-in functionality. But if the algorithm implementation can be improved, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: @wim What can I say, it is like telling someone to use `sorted` when they are trying to implement a sorting algorithm in python.

Comment: But you've used `len`.  You've used `@staticmethod`.  You've used `range`.  Where and why do you draw the line on what's "built-in" and what's not?

Comment: I don't know, I am just looking at it from the point of view of an interviewer who probably want to see problem solving skills instead of how much one knows about built-in functionality.

Comment: Voting to close: the question needs to include the specification in the question itself, not via a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is slow because you're not taking advantage of python's data structures.

Here's a solution that collects results in a dict:

```
class Solution:
    def anagrams(self, strs):
        d = {}
        for word in strs:
            key = tuple(sorted(word))
            try:
                d[key].append(word)
            except KeyError:
                d[key] = [word]
        return [w for ws in d.values() for w in ws if len(ws) > 1]
```

Comment: This does work, but can it work without using sorting? I think it is acceptable  with sorting too, since the overall time complexity becomes `O(mn logn)`

Comment: Yes, make any function which creates a dict key from a word.  The only requirement here is that the key is hashable, and `key(word1) == key(word2)` if and only if word1 and word2 are anagrams.

Comment: @Wajahat Instead of sorting, you can count the letters of the words, similar to what you already did in your helper method, and use those counts (in a hashable format) as the key.

Answer (score 3):

Skip strings you already placed in the set. Don't test them again.

```
# @param strs: A list of strings
# @return: A list of strings
def anagrams(self, strs):
    # write your code here
    ret=set()
    for i in range(0,len(strs)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(strs)):

            # If both anagrams exist in set, there is no need to compare them.
            if i in ret and j in ret:
                continue

            if Solution.isanagram(strs[i],strs[j]):
                ret.add(i)
                ret.add(j)

    return [strs[i] for i in list(ret)]
```

You can also do a length comparison in your anagram test before iterating through the letters. Whenever the strings aren't the same length, they can't be anagrams anyway. Also, when a counter in `chars` reaches -1 when comparing values in t, just return false. Don't iterate through `chars` again.

```
@staticmethod
def isanagram(s, t):
    # Test strings are the same length
    if len(s) != len(t):
        return False

    chars={}
    for i in s:
        if i in chars:
            chars[i]+=1
        else:
            chars[i]=1

    for i in t:
        if i not in chars:
            return False
        else:
            chars[i]-=1
            # If this is below 0, return false
            if chars[i] < 0:
                return False

    for i in chars:
        if chars[i]!=0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I think you might have an error in your if, given that ret contains indices and you're checking if the strings themselves are in ret.

Comment: @StephenTG Good catch. Thanks!

Comment: Tried it, with indices as you missed that. But still exceeds the time limit. Maybe `isanagram` can be improved?

Comment: @Wajahat just thought of one more tweak. But aside from that your solution looks pretty solid. I can't think of much to improve on.

Comment: Length tweak is actually good. Still exceeding time-limit though. Wonder what can be improved besides that.

Comment: @Wajahat Thought of one more. Realized you could just return false when the second iteration finds a negative value in the `chars` dict. This is fun, haha.

Comment: I was so hoping it would work, haha. Still exceeds time-limit ... :(

Comment: for the last for loop, would a sum be better? Sum a list of 0 should be faster than looping through and comparing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing all pairs of strings, you can just create a dictionary (or [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) mapping each of the letter-counts to the words having those counts. For getting the letter-counts, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Afterwards, you just have to get the values from that dict. If you want all words that are anagrams of any other words, just merge the lists that have more than one entry.

```
strings = ["cat", "act", "rat", "hut", "tar", "tact"]
anagrams = defaultdict(list)

for s in strings:
    anagrams[frozenset(Counter(s).items())].append(s)

print([v for v in anagrams.values()])
# [['hut'], ['rat', 'tar'], ['cat', 'act'], ['tact']]
print([x for v in anagrams.values() if len(v) > 1 for x in v])
# ['cat', 'act', 'rat', 'tar']
```

Of course, if you prefer not to use builtin functionality you can with just a few more lines just as well use a regular `dict` instead of `defaultdict` and write your own `Counter`, similar to what you have in your `isanagram` method, just without the comparison part.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Mike's great answer, here is a nice Pythonic way to do it:

```
import collections


class Solution:
    # @param strs: A list of strings
    # @return: A list of strings
    def anagrams(self, strs):
        patterns = Solution.find_anagram_words(strs)
        return [word for word in strs if ''.join(sorted(word)) in patterns]

    @staticmethod
    def find_anagram_words(strs):
        anagrams = collections.Counter(''.join(sorted(word)) for word in strs)
        return {word for word, times in anagrams.items() if times > 1}
```

Comment: Why sort the word before putting it into the counter?

Comment: I use sort to make different words look the same. 'lint' and 'tiln' will look the same, hence they will be counted as the same anagram.

Comment: Looking for algorithm implementation rather than built-in pythonic solutions.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you are using Counter for.

Comment: As @tobias_k said, use `sorted` or `Counter`, not both.

Comment: @wim - Please reread the implementation. Both sorted and Counter are required, as far as I can see :)

Comment: @wim I think you thought, just like I did, that he is sorting, and then counting the letters in the sorted word, but he is counting how often each sorted word appears, then sorting all the words again to find those whose sorted order appears more than once. But I guess that's not the most efficient way either.

Comment: That's neither pythonic nor efficient... `if ... in patterns` goes to `list.__contains__` which iterates.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
str1 = "cafe"
str2 = "face"
def isanagram(s1,s2):
    return all(sorted(list(str1)) == sorted(list(str2)))

if isanagram(str1, str2):
    print "Woo"
```

Comment: Because my implementation is `O(n)` and this is `O(nlogn)`

Comment: `return all(sorted(str1) == sorted(str2))` would be shorter if it were correct. You probably want `return sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)`

Answer (score 0):

The same can be done with a single line of code if you are using Linq in C#

string[] = strs; // Input string array

var result = strs.GroupBy(x => new string(x.ToCharArray().OrderBy(z => z).ToArray())).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Now to Group Anagrams in Python, We have to : Sort the lists. Then, Create a dictionary. Now dictionary will tell us where are those anagrams are( Indices of Dictionary). Then values of the dictionary is the actual indices of the anagrams.

```
def groupAnagrams(words):
 
    # sort each word in the list
    A = [''.join(sorted(word)) for word in words]
    dict = {}
    for indexofsamewords, names in enumerate(A):
     dict.setdefault(names, []).append(indexofsamewords)
    print(dict)
    #{'AOOPR': [0, 2, 5, 11, 13], 'ABTU': [1, 3, 4], 'Sorry': [6], 'adnopr': [7], 'Sadioptu': [8, 16], ' KPaaehiklry': [9], 'Taeggllnouy': [10], 'Leov': [12], 'Paiijorty': [14, 18], 'Paaaikpr': [15], 'Saaaabhmryz': [17], ' CNaachlortttu': [19], 'Saaaaborvz': [20]}
 
    for index in dict.values():
     print([words[i] for i in index])
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # list of words
    words = ["ROOPA","TABU","OOPAR","BUTA","BUAT" , "PAROO","Soudipta",
        "Kheyali Park", "Tollygaunge", "AROOP","Love","AOORP", "Protijayi","Paikpara","dipSouta","Shyambazaar",
        "jayiProti", "North Calcutta", "Sovabazaar"]
 
    groupAnagrams(words)
```

The Output :

```
['ROOPA', 'OOPAR', 'PAROO', 'AROOP', 'AOORP']
['TABU', 'BUTA', 'BUAT']
['Soudipta', 'dipSouta']
['Kheyali Park']
['Tollygaunge']
['Love']
['Protijayi', 'jayiProti']
['Paikpara']
['Shyambazaar']
['North Calcutta']
['Sovabazaar']
```